# Jquery adding elements inside element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery elemnt s and i need to insert inside another elemnt

```
 var s = $('div').html('<button class="mdl-button"></button>');
    var x = s.html('< i class="material-icons" >&#xE834;</i>');
    var a=x.addClass('.mdl-color-text--green-600');
```

then apply the css class to the inner html

```
var t=s.html('<i class="material-icons" >&#xE5CA;</i>');
```

but at the end it returns only

```
< i class="material-icons" >&#xE834;</i>
```

without the surrounding the dive.

Comment: I don't think you understand how [jQuery html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) works.  the variables s, x, a, and t are all the same element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the elements with jQuery instead, so you have references to them

```
var button = $('<button />', { // create a "button"
        'class' : 'mdl-button'
}),
    i = $('<i />', {           // create a "i"
        'class' : 'material-icons',
        html    : '&#xE834;'
});

$('div').empty().append(button, i); // add elements to DOM

i.addClass('.mdl-color-text--green-600'); // add another class to an element
```

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually I think it might be helpful for you to see this in plain JavaScript. jQuery is doing this stuff in the background of the html command.

```
  // First Get your Selector
  let s = document.querySelector('div');
  // Create your element and add any necessary details
  let b = document.createElement('button');
  b.className = 'mdl-button';

  // create your icon and add details
  let i = document.createElement('i');
  i.className = 'material-icons mdl-color-text--green-600';
  i.innerText = "&#xE834;";

  // add icon to button, and button to div element
  b.appendChild(i);
  s.appendChild(b);
```

In your attempt you are doing several things to the same element which causes them to overwrite. Instead you would want to create the elements and then append them.

```
// get your root element, build button and icon
let baseElement = $('div')
,   button = $('<button>').addClass('mdl-button')
,   icon = $('<i>').addClass('material-icons mdl-color-text--green-600').text('&#xE834;');

// append elements
button.append(icon);
baseElement.append(button);
```